# Local vs NonLocal Scope Python

Tags: python, scope

I am trying to understand scopes in Python and am confused in the examples below (I am using Python 3.12.2) -

1.

```
a = 10

def myfunc():
    a = 2
    print(a)

print(a)
myfunc()
```

This gives the output -

```
10
2
```

2. 

```
a = 10

def myfunc():
    print(a)

print(a)
myfunc()
```

This gives the output -

```
10
10
```

3. However, when I do this -

```
a = 10

def myfunc():
    print(a)
    a = 2

print(a)
myfunc()
```

```
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'a' where it is not associated with a value
```

I am not sure how this is different from code example 1. Why is my output not-

```
10
10
```

Comment: Try this out: https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

Comment: If you assign to a variable name _anywhere_ inside of a function, then that variable name is assumed to be local _everywhere_ in the function, even if the assignment has not yet been executed.